# Django ORM taking long time to load

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I have this line of code in my **views.py** file.

```
fund_df = pd.DataFrame(list(FundRolling.objects.filter(code__exact=str(code), rolling=rolling, start_date__gte=start_date, end_date__lte=end_date).values()))
```

**FundRolling** is a model created in Django from MYSQL database. This model has nearly 10 million entries. This line is taking 20 seconds for execution. How can I reduce it to milliseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think DB index can help you to fetch data faster. Try to add this index and don't forget to run migrations. The index may take some time to build.

```
class FundRolling(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        index_together = [
            ['code', 'rolling', 'start_date'],
        ]
```